# I am trying to create an array of interfaces to limit the types passed as an argument

Tags: typescript, interface

```js
interface IQuery {
    match  :any
}

interface IQueryById extends IQuery {

}

interface IQueryByName extends IQuery {

}

class QueryById implements IQueryById {
  ...
};
class QueryByName extends IQueryByName {

}

const listQueryTypes  = [QueryById ,QueryByName  ]; 


function(qry: typeof listQueryTypes  ) {

..

}
```

works but trying to use

```js
const listQueryTypes  = [IQueryById ,IQueryByName  ];
```

does not.

Is there a way to check for any class that implements the interface in an array or is TS limited to
using classes in this manner?

The error message is "...only refers to a type but is being used as a value here."  TS 2693

Comment: The error message pretty much says it. You can't use types as values, because TS types aren't "things" in JS. They are *erased* when translating TS to JS, the runtime kniws nothing at all about interfaces.

Comment: The only practical way to check if an object implements an interface at runtime is to hand-write code that inspects the properties of an object. [Type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) add a little syntax sugar to that idiom. But the absence of type information at runtime beyond built-in types is a fundamental limitation of JS that TS can't fix.

Comment: Why do you want to use interfaces in the array?

Comment: I don’t want to use interfaces in an array. I don’t want to implement them in an array. I want to check that an argument passed to a function has a type in a list of interfaces.

Comment: Then maybe you want  to declare the argument as`qry: IQueryById | IQueryByName`

Comment: Yes that is what I tried and it does work but I really wanted to just specify an array to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T

function doSomething(qry: Constructor<IQueryById | IQueryByName>[]) {
  // ...
}

doSomething([QueryById, QueryByName])
```

note that if you don't finish these classes (even it already declare with `implements`), these type of classes will still cause error until it finished